# Configuring sudo to not prompt for password on non-allowed commands

Tags: security, password, sudo

There is plenty of information on how to make sudo not prompt for passwords (NOPASSWD).

Let's say I have user `alice`, and this line in my sudoers:

`alice    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/myadmintool`

This works just fine. The user can run `sudo /bin/myadmintool` and do stuff.

However, if the user were to do this:

`sudo /bin/bash`

This is what happens:

```
$ sudo /bin/bash
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

Password: 
Sorry, user alice is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as root on myhostname.
```

What I would like to happen is for sudo to jump directly to:

```
Sorry, user alice is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as root on myhostname.
```

... **without** the password prompt.

How can I express this in the sudoers file, just for this user?

Comment: I don't think is possible

Answer (score 4):

After some closer reading of the [sudoers man page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html), I did find a working solution!

My sudoers config for `alice` looks like this:

```
Defaults:alice    !authenticate
alice             ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/myadmintool
```

Keep in mind, this will essentially set NOPASSWD for **ALL** of `alice`'s sudo lines. In my case, this was the intention.

### Further Details

The `authenticate` option is defined in the manual as:

> **authenticate**
>
> If set, users must authenticate themselves via a password (or other means of authentication) before they may run commands. This default may be overridden via the PASSWD and NOPASSWD tags. This flag is on by default.

The `Defaults` option lets you define a user, group, host list, etc, as per:

```
Default_Type ::= 'Defaults' |
             'Defaults' '@' Host_List |
             'Defaults' ':' User_List |
             'Defaults' '!' Cmnd_List |
             'Defaults' '>' Runas_List
```

Since `authenticate` is a boolean configuration option, it can be negated/set to false by doing `!authenticate`.

Answer (score 1):

As workaround you can use a non-interactive mode:

> sudo -n echo test
>   sudo: a password is required

You can make alias for this user:

alias sudo='sudo -n'

Comment: yeah, but that is not configurable on sudoers, where the OP expects an answer.

Comment: @Marcel, that's why i said "workaround". It seems there is no way to make it through sudoers file.